# Average of values of all columns for a given row (without explicitly writing column names)? SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

My SQL Query is

```
select 
concat(3*floor(email/3), '-', 3*floor(email/3) + 2) as `range`, 
avg(`db_1`) as `avg_db1`,
avg(`db_2`) as `avg_db2` 
[
...
...
...

]
from allocation 
group by 1
```

I do not want to explicitly define names of columns as they are large in number and/or may be dynamic. Is it possible to do it with SQL only? (I know the possibilities with a procedural language.)

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'allocation' AND COLUMN_NAME <> "email"
ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION
```

Is it possible to nest this with the above code? (as it generates column names).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is valid for order by but not for group by  ... you must explicitally repeat the code

```
select 
  concat(3*floor(email/3), '-', 3*floor(email/3) + 2) as `range`, 
  avg(`db_1`) as `avg_db1`,
  avg(`db_2`) as `avg_db2` 
  [
  ...
  ...
  ...

  ]
  from allocation 
  group by  concat(3*floor(email/3), '-', 3*floor(email/3) + 2)
```

but starting for the most recent version of mysql  you can use alias

```
  select 
  concat(3*floor(email/3), '-', 3*floor(email/3) + 2) as `range`, 
  avg(`db_1`) as `avg_db1`,
  avg(`db_2`) as `avg_db2` 
  [
  ...
  ...
  ...

  ]
  from allocation 
  group by  `range`
```

the use of alias is not available for sqlserver .. or oracle ..